# TENSORFLOW. Labels and logits doesn't match but I'm sure that they have the same shape

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, computer-vision, deep-learning

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "CNN2.py", line 272, in <module>
    _, l, predictions = session.run([optimizer, cost, y_pred], feed_dict=feed_dict)
  File "/Users/Aldo/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 778, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/Users/Aldo/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 961, in _run
    % (np_val.shape, subfeed_t.name, str(subfeed_t.get_shape())))
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (128,) for Tensor 'y_true:0', which has shape '(128, 1)'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just reshape the labels value to `(128, 1)`

```
labels  = np.reshape(labels, (128, 1))
feed_dict = {..., y_true:labels}
```